# Intersection of 2 plots (sage)

Tags: python, math, plot, intersection, sage

could you please help me with finding points of intersection in graphic

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

@interact
def foo(count=(1,10,1), t=slider(100,1000,100,default=100)):

    plt.cla()    

    dt = 1/t

    x = np.arange(1, step=dt)
    xl = np.arange(1, step=.000001)

    W = np.zeros(t, np.dtype(float))

#Iteration Logarithm
    l = np.sqrt(2*xl*ln(ln(1/xl)))
    plt.plot(xl, l,'r--')    
    plt.plot(xl, -l,'r--')  

    mu, sig = 0, 1

    for ITER in range(1, count+1): #count of W[i] in plot
        for i in range(1, len(W)):
            W[i] = W[i-1] + np.random.normal(mu, sig) * np.sqrt(dt) #Wiener process
        plt.plot(x,W)            

    plt.xlabel('t',fontsize=26)
    plt.ylabel('W(t)',fontsize=26)
    plt.grid(True)
    @interact
    def _dee(deep=slider(0.0001, .4, 0.001, default=.2)): #scale
        plt.xlim(0, deep)
        plt.ylim(-.5, .5)
        plt.show()
```

I use https://cloud.sagemath.com
Can't realize, how to find points of graphic cross each other.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not familiar with sage, getting intersection points given two sampled function should be easy - just **calculate the difference** between them, and **there will be an intersection every time the sign changes**.

```
step=0.1
x= np.arange(-5,5, step=step)

f1 = x**2  - 4
f2 = -x**2 + 4

dif= f2-f1
dif_sign= dif/np.abs(dif) #just the sign of the function
dif_sign_dif= np.diff(dif_sign) #places where the sign changes
change_idxs= np.where(dif_sign_dif!=0)[0] #indexes where the sign changes
print -5+change_idxs*step
```

output:

```
[-2.  2.]
```

Since you are adding brownian motion, you'll get "false positives" once in while, though.